# Fitting a single model to different datasets that include different variables

Tags: bayesian, inference, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose we have two datasets *df_1* with variables {A,B,C} and *df_2* with variables {A,C,D} (A & C are the only mutual variable in the two datasets). Our aim is to predict A using B & C or C & D (depending on which pair is given). The simplest approach is to model A using *df_1* and *df_2* separately and have two different fits suitable for each pair of inputs. Now I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use a hierarchical model where we fit A ~ B + C and A ~ C + D at the same time and allow for information sharing via a hierarchical structure to boost the learning of the effect of C on A?
2. Can we use a change point model in this 3D space (which I suppose makes it a change plane model) to have two planes instead of a single one fitted to the data?

**Note: I don't like P-Splines to be used here for dealing with non-linearity because it harms interpretability and that's why I prefer using change points (change planes) to report the linear effect of B and C on A in maybe two or three different regions in the space.**

Comment: With regard to (1), a hierarchical model usually refers to some sort of repetitive or nested structure within the observations of your data within a single model, as opposed to multiple distinct models. I don't think there's a coherent Bayesian formulation for this problem because you are simultaneously saying there are two distinct ways the data can be formed (A ~ B + C and A ~ C + D) which must necessarily be at odds. 

Sometimes, people perform model averaging, but this scenario usually implies both models are trained on the same data. Clearly that won't happen here.

Comment: @ChristopherKrapu what if I told you that B & D are both trying to measure the same thing but with two different approaches and A ~ B + C and A ~ C + D are not really different except for the choice of measuring one feature?